# Apache Digester How do I get some xml nested within a tag as a literal string?

Tags: java, apache-commons-digester

I am parsing a XML with Digester. A part of it contains content formatted in cryptic pseudo-HTML XML elements which I need to transform into an PDF. That will be done via Apache FOP. Hence I need to access the xml element which contains the content elements directly and pipe it to FOP. To do so the [Digester FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Digester/FAQ) states that one either

> Wrap the nested xml in CDATA

or

> If this can't be done then you need to use a NodeCreateRule to create a DOM node representing the body tag and its children, then serialise that DOM node back to text

Since it is a third party XML the `CDATA` approach could only be done via (another) XSLT which I hestitate to do.

It looks like this issue should be solvable via [NodeCreateRule](http://commons.apache.org/digester/commons-digester-1.5/docs/api/org/apache/commons/digester/NodeCreateRule.html) but I can not figure out how to get it done.

The documentation states that `NodeCreateRule` will push a Node onto the stack however I can only get it to pass null.

I tried

```
digester.addRule(docPath + "/contents", new NodeCreateRule());
digester.addCallMethod(docPath + "/contents", "setContentsXML");
```

setContentsXML expects a Element parameter.

I also tried [this](http://javalobby.org/java/forums/t92400.html) and [this](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2006/10/custom-digester-rule.html) without any luck.

I am using the latest stable Digester. Would be thankful for any advice.

**Update:**
I [found the bug](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/zxErAZEuvSzjmbaxaQfp)  . The result on my system is null, too. I am using JDK 6u24

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case as well as the linked bug lays in the proper serialisation of an `Element`. In my case the mentioned null value was not returned by Digester but by `Element#toString()`. I assume something changed since JDK 1.4.

By the bug example:

`result` contains **another** (text-)node with the actual content. toString() however simply takes the content of the Element instance it is called uppon. 
The Element tree has to be serialized explicitly. For example with the serialization method in [this](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2006/10/custom-digester-rule.html) useage example of `NodeCreateRule`.

In case someone else tries to use [that](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2006/10/custom-digester-rule.html) with Digester 3: you have to change the method signature `SetSerializedNodeRule#end()` to `SetSerializedNodeRule#end(String, String)`.